# Чем лучше заменять пробел в ЧПУ?

Tags: seo, чпу

Добрый день, друзья и коллеги!

Немного философский вопрос: 
"*На что лучше заменить пробелы в ЧПУ на кирилице? И как это повлияет на выдачу?*"

**Вариант 1:** Минус, он же тире "-"

**Вариант 2:** Нижнее подчеркивание "_"

**Вариант 3:** Плюсик, он же крестик "+"

Ваши варианты?

UPD. Нашел один аргумент против "_", нижнее подчеркивание запрещено в имени домена, а "-" разрешено.

Comment: 1 или 2 вариант! На ХэшКоде как видите 1 вариант!

Comment: Согласен, однако читается помоему лучше с "_", хотя в сети народ пишет, что это спец символ и его лучше не использовать, но с другой стороны в выдаче поисковиков присутствуют в равной степени оба варианта.

Comment: Palmervan, спасибо, полезный ответ. В данном вопросе меня интересует больше SEO, а не юзабилити. Поэтому и интересуюсь, может кто знает, как к этим символам относятся поисковые роботы. Ведь у ЧПУ двойное назначение, с одной стороны они удобнее для пользователей, что понятно из названия, но с другой поисковые роботы могут проиндексировать их также как заголовок страницы, а это немалый вес.

Comment: Очевидно же, что «_». Ибо остальные символы имеют уже совсем другие значения. Скажем так, все уже привыкли так. И нету смысла делать разрыва шаблона. )

Comment: @Eugene, ИМХО "-" тоже неплохо.

Comment: @invincible если ответ полезный, по желанию можите его принять, коммент сделал ответом)

Comment: Имхо, поисковикам глубоко наплевать какой из этих символов является разделителем. Во всяком случает популярным типа Google и Яндекс.

Comment: Пока не видел где применяется плюсик :). Обычно так то применяют в замену пробела "_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос) Я думаю что нет смысла страдать мега оригинальносью и менять пробелы на что-то невообразимое типа(&, :) ну это я к примеру... Я не думаю что посетитель зашедший на ваш сайт будет разглядывать какой красивый у вас url. 1 вариант более приемлим и используется в большинстве случаев с точки зрения профессионального подхода!

Answer (score 6):

Чаще всего встречаю:

> Латиницу _
>
> Кириллицу -

Comment: +1, но вот в этом то и вопрос, что это просто хорошая традиция, либо в этом есть какой-то смысл.
Как пользователю мне больше нравится вот_такая_ссылка, но как разработчику мне кажется, что вот-такая-будет лучше, хотя бы потому, что в именах домена запрещен символ "_"

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Как вариант можно использовать знак "**›**".

Для **SEO** всё это не важно. Здесь вы можете быть вольны и выбирать то, что вам больше всего нравится. Хотя, конечно, такие знаки как &,@,#,* использовать не стоит :)

Comment: Знак ">"? Омфг.

Comment: @Construct Та чё? будет красиво

`чем%3Eлучше%3Eзаменять%3Eпробел%3Eв%3Eчпу`

По моему даже очень читабельно XD) утрирую)

Comment: @Palmervan, а, так это и не greater than ещё, а что-то другое, присмотритесь.

Comment: @Construct присмпотрелся... жесть... @Iwww этот символ ни гугль ни яшя не отдупляют, это же нада до такого додуматься... а если я захочу вбить руками какой нить адрес типа

    `http://website.ws/ya›plakal`

где этот символ на клаве искать?)))

Comment: Что-то я не подумал... Вы правы.